# Rails: ActiveRecord Query for has_many :through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

How to query for *Companies* with a certain *Branch* in a "has_many :through" relationship?

```
  #company.rb
  has_many :branch_choices
  has_many :branches, :through => :branch_choices
```

"Find all companies with Branch ID 3"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Company.includes(:branches).where(:branches => {:id => 3})
```

or

```
Branch.find(3).companies
```

**UPDATE**
Actually, there's one downside to the first snippet: it eagerly loads branches along with the companies. To avoid this overhead you may consider using a left join:

```
Company.
  joins("LEFT JOIN `branch_choices` ON `branch_choices`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`").
  where(:branch_choices => {:branch_id => 3})
```

Comment: In addition, how would the first line look like as a Scope?

Comment: `scope :filter_by_branch, lambda{|branch_id| includes(:branches).where(:branches => {:id => branch_id})`

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick and avoids extra queries:

```rb
Company.joins(:branches).where(:branches => {:id => 3})
```